# Python scatter chart matplotlib.pyplot with specific conditions

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, scatter

I am using the below script for plotting the chart using python:

```
ax = matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(dataset.x,dataset.y,s=dataset.Colorcode*30,c=pandas.Categorical(dataset.y).codes,cmap=matplotlib.pyplot.cm.Spectral)
for line in range(0,dataset.shape[0]):
    matplotlib.pyplot.text(dataset.x[line],dataset.y[line],dataset.Colorcode[line],horizontalalignment='center',size='small',weight='semibold')
matplotlib.pyplot.grid()
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

A chart is plotted as below:

[image: current plot]

As you can see it's with multiple colors and I only want to plot with three colors as below:

[image: desired plot]

Can you please guide me on how I can achieve this? I am new to python.